# Where can I find a (well-documented) simple solver for linear optimization problems with both equality and inequality constraints?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, linear-programming, computational-mathematics, numerical-optimization

I need to solve a linear optimization problem subject to both equality and inequality constraints in C++ (using MSVC 15). Mathematically, this can be solved by the simplex algorithm. Since I don't want to write my own implementation, I've searched the internet for a library - unfortunately, without success. Actually, [SoPlex](https://soplex.zib.de/doc-4.0.2/html/index.php) seems to be promising, but the documentation is basically the plain doxygen description of the code. This is what I encountered all the time (if there is a documentation at all).

All I need is a simple solver, since I only want to test something which I will later replace by a more sophisticated optimization technique.

Comment: Have you checked [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/)?

Comment: I haven't really gone far with it, but there's e.g. CPLEX from IBM, which has a free version.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I've taken a look. I'm interested in solving a problem of the following kind: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3353801/47771. How would I do that with GLPK?

Answer (score 1):

Google OR tools can probably do what you need https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/cpp

The COIN-OR project has CLP which is also a good CLP solver but has kind of an awkward API if I remember correctly https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp