# How can we solve this simple linear program?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, computational-mathematics, numerical-optimization

Let $$a:=\begin{pmatrix}.2&.1\\.7&.05\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$b:=\begin{pmatrix}.01&.9\\.4&.3\end{pmatrix}.$$ I want to maximize $$\sum_{ij}a_{ij}\min(x_i,b_{ij}y_j)$$ subject to $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\ge0$ and $x_1+x_2=y_1+y_2=1$. The idea is to introduce auxiliary variables $z_{ij}$ and maximize $$\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}z_{ij}$$ subject to $z_{ij}\le x_i$ and $z_{ij}\le b_{ij}y_j$.

It's been a while since I thought about linear optimization. If I remember correctly, the constraints usually need to be of the form $Ax\le b$ (or $Ax=b$), where $A$ and $b$ are constant. How can I rewrite the problem in such a "standard" form?

I would like to solve this problem with [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) (just as a starting point for my understanding how this library works). So, if anyone knows how the constraints above can be specified in the API I would be very thankful.

**EDIT**: My guess is we need to consider $$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&-1&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&-b_{11}&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&-b_{12}&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&-b_{21}&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&-b_{22}&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}}_{=:\:A}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\y_1\\y_2\\z_{11}\\z_{12}\\z_{21}\\z_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}=1\\=1\\\le0\\\le0\\\le0\\\le0\\\le0\\\le0\\\le0\\\le0\end{pmatrix}$$ or (if we need to eliminate the inequality constraints by introducing further auxiliary variables $u_{ij},v_{ij}\ge0$) $$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&-b_{11}&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&-b_{12}&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&-b_{21}&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&-b_{22}&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}}_{=:\:A}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\y_1\\y_2\\z_{11}\\z_{12}\\z_{21}\\z_{22}\\u_{11}\\u_{12}\\u_{21}\\u_{22}\\v_{11}\\v_{12}\\v_{21}\\v_{22}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: your best option : https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/

Comment: @Kuifje I need to solve problems of this kind inside a C++ program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your formulation is correct.  Adapting the example from the introduction to GLPK, I get the following solution, which you may want to check.

```
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.65
10 rows, 8 columns, 20 non-zeros
      0: obj =  -0.000000000e+00 inf =   2.000e+00 (2)
      2: obj =  -0.000000000e+00 inf =   0.000e+00 (0)
*     7: obj =   2.820000000e-01 inf =   0.000e+00 (0)
OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND

objective = 0.282; x1 = 0.6; x2 = 0.4; y1 = 1; y2 = 0
z11 = 0.01; z12 = 0; z21 = 0.4; z22 = 0
```

The code is as follows:

```
#include 
#include 

int main(void) {
  glp_prob *lp = glp_create_prob();
  glp_set_prob_name(lp, "0xbadf00d");
  glp_set_obj_dir(lp, GLP_MAX);

  glp_add_rows(lp, 10);
  glp_set_row_name(lp, 1, "e1");
  glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 1, GLP_FX, 1.0, 1.0);
  glp_set_row_name(lp, 2, "e2");
  glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 2, GLP_FX, 1.0, 1.0);
  glp_set_row_name(lp, 3, "u11");
  glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 3, GLP_UP, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_row_name(lp, 4, "u12");
  glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 4, GLP_UP, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_row_name(lp, 5, "u21");
  glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 5, GLP_UP, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_row_name(lp, 6, "u22");
  glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 6, GLP_UP, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_row_name(lp, 7, "v11");
  glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 7, GLP_UP, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_row_name(lp, 8, "v12");
  glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 8, GLP_UP, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_row_name(lp, 9, "v21");
  glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 9, GLP_UP, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_row_name(lp, 10, "v22");
  glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 10, GLP_UP, 0.0, 0.0);

  glp_add_cols(lp, 8);
  glp_set_col_name(lp, 1, "x1");
  glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 1, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 1, 0);
  glp_set_col_name(lp, 2, "x2");
  glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 2, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 2, 0);
  glp_set_col_name(lp, 3, "y1");
  glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 3, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 3, 0);
  glp_set_col_name(lp, 4, "y2");
  glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 4, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 4, 0);
  glp_set_col_name(lp, 5, "z11");
  glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 5, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 5, 0.2);
  glp_set_col_name(lp, 6, "z12");
  glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 6, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 6, 0.1);
  glp_set_col_name(lp, 7, "z21");
  glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 7, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 7, 0.7);
  glp_set_col_name(lp, 8, "z22");
  glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 8, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
  glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 8, 0.05);

  int ia[1+1000], ja[1+1000];
  double ar[1+1000];
  ia[1]  =  1, ja[1]  = 1, ar[1]  =  1.0; // x1 + x2 = 1
  ia[2]  =  1, ja[2]  = 2, ar[2]  =  1.0;
  ia[3]  =  2, ja[3]  = 3, ar[3]  =  1.0; // y1 + y2 = 1
  ia[4]  =  2, ja[4]  = 4, ar[4]  =  1.0;
  ia[5]  =  3, ja[5]  = 1, ar[5]  = -1.0; // z11 le x1
  ia[6]  =  3, ja[6]  = 5, ar[6]  =  1.0;
  ia[7]  =  4, ja[7]  = 1, ar[7]  = -1.0; // z12 le x1
  ia[8]  =  4, ja[8]  = 6, ar[8]  =  1.0;
  ia[9]  =  5, ja[9]  = 2, ar[9]  = -1.0; // z21 le x2
  ia[10] =  5, ja[10] = 7, ar[10] =  1.0;
  ia[11] =  6, ja[11] = 2, ar[11] = -1.0; // z22 le x2
  ia[12] =  6, ja[12] = 8, ar[12] =  1.0;
  ia[13] =  7, ja[13] = 3, ar[13] = -0.01;// z11 le b11*y1
  ia[14] =  7, ja[14] = 5, ar[14] =  1.0;
  ia[15] =  8, ja[15] = 4, ar[15] = -0.9; // z12 le b12*y2
  ia[16] =  8, ja[16] = 6, ar[16] =  1.0;
  ia[17] =  9, ja[17] = 3, ar[17] = -0.4; // z21 le b21*y1
  ia[18] =  9, ja[18] = 7, ar[18] =  1.0;
  ia[19] = 10, ja[19] = 4, ar[19] = -0.3; // z22 le b22*y2
  ia[20] = 10, ja[20] = 8, ar[20] =  1.0;
  glp_load_matrix(lp, 20, ia, ja, ar);

  glp_simplex(lp, NULL);

  double objective, x1, x2, y1, y2, z11, z12, z21, z22;
  objective = glp_get_obj_val(lp);
  x1  = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 1);
  x2  = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 2);
  y1  = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 3);
  y2  = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 4);
  z11 = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 5);
  z12 = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 6);
  z21 = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 7);
  z22 = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 8);
  printf("\nobjective = %g; x1 = %g; x2 = %g; y1 = %g; y2 = %g\n",
         objective, x1, x2, y1, y2);
  printf("z11 = %g; z12 = %g; z21 = %g; z22 = %g\n",
         z11, z12, z21, z22);

  glp_delete_prob(lp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we say anything about uniqueness? It seems like
$x_1 = 0.01$, $x_2 = 0.99$, $y_1 = 1$, $y_2 = 0$ is a solution as well.

Comment: Good catch.  For $y_1=1$ and $y_2=0$, the $z_{ij}$ values do not change as long as $1/100 \leq x_1 \leq 3/5$.  So, there are infinitely many solutions with the maximum objective value. GLPK returns one extreme of the range, and you found the other.

Comment: Can we give sufficient conditions on the matrices $a,b$ (possibly considered in more generality as $n\times n$-matrices) ensuring the uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: The objective vector should not be orthogonal to any edge of the polytope.  After the LP program has been solved, GLPK lets you produce a sensitivity analysis report.  The description of the analysis starts at page 92 of the documentation.  There are also API functions that let one analyze the solution from within the program (p. 117).  I've never used them, though.